# Cannot find java runtime on MacOS (M1 silicon) after installing openjdk

Tags: java, macos

I have installed openjdk@11 and openjdk (21) on MacOS.
Proof: when I typed `brew install openjdk` it says:

```
Warning: openjdk 21 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 21, run:
  brew reinstall openjdk
```

However when I run `java --version` or whatever commands it says it cannot find the runtime. I think it is because the path is not set correctly. But I simply could not locate the runtime. I have checked the following places:

```
~/opt/
/library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
/System/Library/
```

Nothing is there. What did I miss?

Comment: "it says" You ought to include the attempts and messages resulting from the attempts. But I think you'll get more help at superuser or askdifferent. This is less of a coding problem than a configuration problem.

Comment: What did you mean? The attempt is shown in `brew install openjdk` and the messages are quoted below, the "Warning" part. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Thanks I'll check out superuser too.

Comment: The attempt to find java. Not the attempt to install it. Seems pretty obvious that the antecedent of "it" in your statement is not the brew command but some other attempt to execute java or find all the javas that are installed. Those are the its that you haven't shown.

Comment: `brew info java` -- does that tell you where it's installed?

Comment: Tip for future use: [*SDKMAN!*](https://sdkman.io/).

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas thanks I found it! `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/21`. I'll check out what JAVA_HOME exactly means and point it to a folder.

Answer (score 0):

Since you installed Java previously with homebrew, you can use the `brew info` command to see the details of your installation:

```
% brew info java

openjdk: stable 15.0.1 (bottled) [keg-only]
Development kit for the Java programming language
https://openjdk.java.net/
/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/15.0.1 (614 files, 324.9MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2020-12-09 at 09:06:07
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/openjdk.rb
License: Cannot Represent
```

Comment: brew info openjdk in my case gives an explanation that a keg is not symlinked nor added to the PATH. That probably clarifies the issue.

Comment: @aled you can modify the answer if you think it is helpful for future readers